# scrollTo(target, options) is not working in mobile. (Locomotive scroll)

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling, locomotivejs, locomotive-scroll

I am facing a strange issue. On desktop, everything is working fine but when I am switching to mobile some strange things are happening, and don't know why. scrollTo(target, options) is not working at all. On desktop horizontal mode is on and for mobile, I have turned it off & the smooth is also turned off on mobile.

My code:

```
const lscroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
  el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
  smooth: true,
  repeat: false,
  getDirection: true,
  direction: 'horizontal',
  tablet: {
    smooth: false,
    direction: "vertical"
  },
  smartphone: {
    smooth: false,
    direction: "vertical"
  },
});
```

I have also tried with smooth true for mobile but nothing happened. Please help me with this.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Use it in html file like this

```
<a href="#here" data-scroll-to>
    scroll to explore
 </a>


..

..

 <section  id="here">`enter code here`  </section>
```

It should work  if locomotive scroll is properly initialized in JS